# add reference in VBA? which one? how do i know?

Tags: excel, dll, reference, vba

```
Sub examp()
Dim r As String, r1 As String
r = M_C_0
r1 = repalce(r, "_", " ")

End Sub
```

above is my code. i am trying to use the replace function. but the error returns and says Compile error: sub or function not defined.

well, what i am thinking is that i need to go to Tools>>refeerence and to check one of the many boxes to establish the reference. but how do i know which box should i choice. i went to the msdn website
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5(v=vs.90).aspx

and found something like:

### Requirements

Namespace: Microsoft.VisualBasic

Module: Strings

Assembly: Visual Basic Runtime Library (in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll)

i guss the way i am adding reference has something to do with this requirements. i am not there yet. and i am stucked here. any help please???????

Best

Xintong

Answer (score 0):

Fix your spelling:

**Replace()**

is not the same as:

**Repalce()**